# Distribution of elliptic curves with rank 2?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory, elliptic-curve-generation

An elliptic curve defined over a finite field is either cyclic, or a direct sum of two cyclic groups. In cryptography, we use exclusively the former. I was wondering if there is any result on how common (or rare) are rank-2 elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ for a prime power $q$.

(They don't seem rare. For a fixed prime $p$ of 64 bits, I sampled 1000 random curves defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and got 170 curves of rank 2. Same experiment with a 128-bit $p$ yields 208 such curves. )

Comment: It's not true that we only use curves with cyclic group structure: Pairing-friendly curves have full $\ell$‑torsion defined over a small extension! It might not always be obvious with the way things are written down, but there's always an $E[\ell]=\mathbb Z/\ell\times\mathbb Z/\ell$ somewhere under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For prime $p$, let us denote by $C(p)$ the probability that a random elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies that $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic (this depends slightly on how one defines a “random” elliptic curve, but most reasonable ways—choosing the isomorphism class at random, choosing the $j$-invariant at random and then a random twist, choosing the short Weierstrass coefficients at random, etc.—should give basically the same result asymptotically). Then I claim that, for large $p$, we have:
$$C(p) = \prod_{\ell
|p-1} \Big(1-\frac{1}{\ell^3-\ell}\Big) + o(1), \tag{1}$$
where the product is over all the prime divisors of $p-1$ (and one could write a more precise bound for the error term if one wanted). This implies in particular that:
$$\limsup_{p\to\infty} C(p) = 1-\frac{1}{2^3-2} = \frac{5}{6} \approx 0.833,$$
and:
$$\liminf_{p\to\infty} C(p) = \prod_{\ell} \Big(1-\frac{1}{\ell^3-\ell}\Big) \approx 0.788.$$

This is because $E$ is non-cyclic (I don't think “rank 2” is a very good name for this) if and only if there exists a prime $\ell$ such that $E$ has full $\ell$-torsion over $\mathbb{F}_p$, or equivalently, such that the Frobenius endomorphism of $E$ acts as the identity on $E[\ell]$.

Now, standard equidistribution results (see e.g. Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.4332) of Castryk and Hubrechts) say that, for fixed $\ell$ and large $p$, the Frobenius acting on $E[\ell]$ is essentially uniformly distributed among $2\times 2$ matrices of determinant $p$ over $\mathbb{F}_\ell$ as $E$ ranges over elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This means that the probability of getting the identity is $0$ if $p\not\equiv 1\pmod\ell$, and $1/\#\mathop{\textrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{F}_\ell) = 1/(\ell^3-\ell)$ otherwise.

This gives formula $(1)$, and the lim inf and lim sup results are obtained by choosing large primes $p$ that are congruent to $1$ (resp., something else) modulo all the primes $\ell$ from $3$ to some arbitrarily large bound.

(And as you can see, the probability you get depends much more on what the factors of $p-1$ look like than on the size of $p$ per se).

Comment: Thanks Professor. Could you give a hint on why "rank 2" is not a good name for non-cyclic curves?

Comment: The rank of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ is usually defined as the dimension of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$,which for a torsion module is always zero.